# compare_means() and stat_compare_means(), why different outcome on same data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have issues adding statistics to my plots. Whenever I calculate the significance using compare_means() the outcome:

```
compare_means(Protein ~ Treatment, data = patient_data[])

# A tibble: 1 x 8
  .y.       group1 group2       p  p.adj p.format p.signif method  
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 Protein Treated   Ctrl   0.00794 0.0079 0.0079   **       Wilcoxon
```

is very different from when I try to add that to the graph using stat_compare_means()

```
ggplot(patient_data[], aes(x = Treatment, y = Protein, color = Experiment)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "wilcox.test")
```

[image: Graph]

Seems something funky is going on when plotting, no idea what though. It would be great if anyone knows what could cause the issue.

cheers,
Menno

PS: the data is a subset of a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
Sample.Name Protein Experiment  Treatment
Sample_name_01  1070    01  Ctrl
Sample_name_02  222 02  Ctrl
Sample_name_03  243 02  Ctrl
Sample_name_04  264 03  Ctrl
Sample_name_05  285 03  Ctrl
Sample_name_06  187 01  Treated
Sample_name_07  55  02  Treated
Sample_name_08  72  02  Treated
Sample_name_09  52  03  Treated
Sample_name_10  55  03  Treated
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal viable dataset for us to replicate your issue.

Comment: And do look at where these functions come from. Same package? Same authors? Same help pages?

Comment: @IRTFM, they are both from ggpubr

Comment: The p value that is printed are the comparison of Control vs Treatment for each of the experiment factor, i.e. p = 1, 0.33, 0.33 for experiments 1, 2 and 3 respectively. You can see this if you run `ggplot(df, aes(x = Treatment, y = Protein)) + geom_jitter(width = 0.1) + facet_wrap(~Experiment) + stat_compare_means(method = "wilcox.test")`.

Comment: This will give the same result as the compare_means p value: `ggplot(df, aes(x = Treatment, y = Protein)) + geom_jitter(width = 0.1, aes(col=factor(Experiment))) + stat_compare_means(method = "wilcox.test")`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot!
And it sort of makes sense, but then I'd expected compare_means() to do the same, anyway..